# Como mostrar el resultado de una operacion en javascript a jade

Tags: nodejs, express, jade

El objetivo es obtener los datos de una operación `javascript` y mostrar el resultado en la página, el código es el siguiente:

```
doctype html
html
 head
  title Mi Pagina

  script(type="text/javascript").
   var resultado = localStorage.getItem("valor");

 body
  h1 resultado
```

Estoy utilizando el `localStorage` para poder obtener valores que inserto desde otra pagina y que necesito mostrar en esta, pero ya intente distintas opciones para mostrarlo y no me funcionan.

```
h1 #{resultado}
h1=resultado
```

si utilizo la opcion del caracter - con jade no funciona ya que me lanza error que menciona que la funcion getItem no existe

```
var resultado = localStorage.getItem("valor")
h1=resultado
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. el elemento tiene que tener un ID (usando el `#` delante y pegado `h1#resultado`)
2. para meter texto dentro de un elemento común (que no es un input ni un textArea ni similar) se usa textContent (en los viejos IE innerText), nunca innerHTML porque es inseguro por la inyección de código y escape de caracteres.
3. La sección script conviene ponerla en el body para que se renderice más rápido

`ejemplo:`

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Mi Pagina

  body
    h1#resultado
    script(type="text/javascript").
      resultado.textContent = localStorage.getItem("valor");
```

Podría no funcionar porque todavía no están listos los elementos, mejor meter el script en un evento:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Mi Pagina

  body
    h1#resultado
    script(type="text/javascript").
      window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        resultado.textContent = localStorage.getItem("valor");
      });
```